# Selecting optimal lag values for Neural Network in univariate time series forecasting - How many lags to use as input variables?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, lags, univariate

What is the recommended approach for selecting lag values in a univariate time series forecasting problem, specifically for input variables in a feedforward neural network (FFNN)? In my research project, I am analyzing **monthly** electricity consumption data using data mining techniques, and I obtained lag values based on ACF values and cut-off lags. However, all the Pearson and Spearman correlations of the original data set and each and every lag value came out to be significant, and I am unsure of how many lag values to use as input variables. What should be the best course of action in such a situation?

Comment: I hope that I'm wrong, but I do not expect anyone here to have a special solution for this particular problem. General strategies, like evaluating a range of reasonable lag ranges with look-forward testing or block-CV are appropriate.